# Can't override target-specific variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have such Makefile:

```
print: var1=inside

print:
    @echo $(var1)
```

When I run `var1=outside make -e print`. I expected to see:

```
outside
```

[Because of](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

> Variables provided on the command line (and in the environment if the ‘-e’ option is in force) will take precedence.

But I get:

```
inside
```

Is it a correct output?

Comment: Target specific variables aren't supported in all versions. You should print the `.FEATURES` variable and look for `target-specific`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html

Answer (score 2):

It is expected; whether or not it's correct I guess depends on who you ask.

The `-e` option is in effect for "global" variables in makefiles, but target-specific variables take precedence over globally-scoped variables.

Personally I think `-e` was a mistake and never should have existed.  But, you know, POSIX and all.  Even though it exists I recommend that it be avoided.  It's far, far too easy to completely mess up your build in confusing and surprising ways.

*ETA* Well, maybe it's not expected.  Maybe it is a bug.  Where did you get that quote you provided?  With just that sentence from a 225-page document it's hard to say... a link or at least a section name would be helpful.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

Target-specific variables have the same priority as any other makefile variable.

Comment: Well, then it's certainly a bug.  Whether it's a bug in the manual or a bug in the code is not at all clear (to me).  I still recommend you avoid `-e`.

Comment: maybe you know a workaround? how overriding of a target variable can be done from CLI?

Comment: I must place it after `make -e target var1=something` !

Comment: You've sort of got it right.  `-e` is terrible because it causes _any_ variable in your environment to take precedence over any variable in your makefile.  You likely don't know what variables are in your environment at any given time, and you may not know all the variables in your makefile.  This makes it completely unpredictable.  So you should not use `-e`.

Comment: In contrast, each variable you assign on the command line overrides virtually every instance of _that_ variable in the makefile, and since you explicitly put it on the command line you know exactly which variables are being overridden and which are not.  However, you should not use the `-e` option in this case so your sample command line above is wrong in that way.  It should just be `make var=value ...`

Comment: You can read more about this: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html